# Are multiple calls to java SaxParser.parse(String, Handler) Legal?

Tags: java, xml, pdf, itext, sax

I have a java SAX parser which I would like to call multiple times on the same Handler with different XML files. I am using this in conjunction with iText to create a multi-page PDF document where some pages have one XML tag map and other pages have another. For example,

```
parser.parse("xmlFile1", handler);
parser.parse("xmlFile2", handler);
```

When I try to do this, I get a java.lang.RuntimeException thrown with the following stacktrace:

```
DocumentException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The document is not open.
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getDirectContent(PdfWriter.java:695)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.carriageReturn(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.Document.add(Unknown Source)
at myClass.myCode(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:345)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:223)
at myClass.myCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
```

Does the SaxParser.parse method implicitly call document.close()? Or is there some other problem in my code which I need to isolate and correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Reusing the same parser is legal (as long as it is not used concurrently)
- The parser triggers an "endDocument". This seems to close the iText document here.. But this is not done by the parser - this is code from your handler.

Comment: I had ControlOpenClose set to true which causes the SAXiTextHandler to automatically close the document when handleEndingTags is called from the endElement method. For details on the implementation of SAXiTextHandler, see the following code: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/lowagie/text/xml/SAXiTextHandler.java.html